# ClassNotFound exception during deploy

Tags: java, deployment, intellij-idea, jboss7.x, classnotfoundexception

I am in trouble! I am trying to deploy my app on `JBoss AS 7.1.1.Final` by `IntelliJ IDEA 11` and during deploy I have this exception :

```
12:23:42,566 ERROR [org.jboss.msc.service.fail] (MSC service thread 1-4) MSC00001: Failed to start service jboss.deployment.subunit."kladr.ear"."kladr-ejb-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar".POST_MODULE: org.jboss.msc.service.StartException in service jboss.deployment.subunit."kladr.ear"."kladr-ejb-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar".POST_MODULE: Failed to process phase POST_MODULE of subdeployment "kladr-ejb-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar" of deployment "kladr.ear"
    at org.jboss.as.server.deployment.DeploymentUnitPhaseService.start(DeploymentUnitPhaseService.java:119) [jboss-as-server-7.1.1.Final.jar:7.1.1.Final]
    at org.jboss.msc.service.ServiceControllerImpl$StartTask.startService(ServiceControllerImpl.java:1811) [jboss-msc-1.0.2.GA.jar:1.0.2.GA]
    at org.jboss.msc.service.ServiceControllerImpl$StartTask.run(ServiceControllerImpl.java:1746) [jboss-msc-1.0.2.GA.jar:1.0.2.GA]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.runTask(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:886) [rt.jar:1.6.0_37]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:908) [rt.jar:1.6.0_37]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:662) [rt.jar:1.6.0_37]
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Error getting reflective information for class com.kmware.ttk.kladr.dao.KladrUpdateDAO with ClassLoader ModuleClassLoader for Module "deployment.kladr.ear.kladr-ejb-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar:main" from Service Module Loader
    at org.jboss.as.server.deployment.reflect.DeploymentReflectionIndex.getClassIndex(DeploymentReflectionIndex.java:70) [jboss-as-server-7.1.1.Final.jar:7.1.1.Final]
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/linuxense/javadbf/DBFException
    at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredMethods0(Native Method) [rt.jar:1.6.0_37]
    at java.lang.Class.privateGetDeclaredMethods(Class.java:2427) [rt.jar:1.6.0_37]
    at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredMethods(Class.java:1791) [rt.jar:1.6.0_37]
    at org.jboss.as.server.deployment.reflect.ClassReflectionIndex.<init>(ClassReflectionIndex.java:65) [jboss-as-server-7.1.1.Final.jar:7.1.1.Final]
    at org.jboss.as.server.deployment.reflect.DeploymentReflectionIndex.getClassIndex(DeploymentReflectionIndex.java:66) [jboss-as-server-7.1.1.Final.jar:7.1.1.Final]
    ... 10 more
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.linuxense.javadbf.DBFException from [Module "deployment.kladr.ear.kladr-ejb-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar:main" from Service Module Loader]
    at org.jboss.modules.ModuleClassLoader.findClass(ModuleClassLoader.java:190)
    at org.jboss.modules.ConcurrentClassLoader.performLoadClassUnchecked(ConcurrentClassLoader.java:468)
    at org.jboss.modules.ConcurrentClassLoader.performLoadClassChecked(ConcurrentClassLoader.java:456)
    at org.jboss.modules.ConcurrentClassLoader.performLoadClassChecked(ConcurrentClassLoader.java:423)
    at org.jboss.modules.ConcurrentClassLoader.performLoadClass(ConcurrentClassLoader.java:398)
    at org.jboss.modules.ConcurrentClassLoader.loadClass(ConcurrentClassLoader.java:120)
    ... 15 more
```

This library `linuxense` is presented in `pom.xml`. And i does not know what the reason of this error. Here is the part of pom:

```
....
  <dependency>
           <groupId>com.linuxense</groupId>
           <artifactId>javadbf</artifactId>
           <version>0.4.0</version>
  </dependency>
....
```

App is deploying in EAR archive.
EAR contains EJB.jar and WEB.war apps (with different names).

What could be the reason of this?

Comment: Does the JAR with the EJBs contain the linuxense jar? Or does the EJB itself? The part of the `pom.xml` you've shown, is it the EJB's `pom.xml`, the WAR's `pom.xml` or the parent `pom.xml`?

Comment: part of pom is the EJB's pom.xml. I put linuxense.jar to ejb.jar manually and it works fine, but i dont understand why it does not put there automatically?

Comment: What is the `<packaging>` of your EJB's pom.xml?

Comment: Maybe http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7494927/maven-ejb-project-package-with-dependencies covers what you want?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `ClassNotFoundException` is caused by the linuxense jar not being present in the deployment. Take a look at [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7494927/maven-ejb-project-package-with-dependencies) for a possible way to work around this.